# Generate Java class hierarchy from Neo4j graph

Tags: java, neo4j

I have a Neo4j graph which defines a particular ontology. It was built using cypher statements and imported into Neo4j. For this graph, I would like to generate the corresponding Java classes with the node properties representing the fields in the corresponding Java class. What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't be too hard. Just create the java-code with either some templating or directly with StringBuilder.

Just iterate over one node per label (assuming the have all the same properties).

1. Create the class
2. create the fields according to property name, type and current value as default value
3. create the field representing relationships to other nodes by inspecting the label on the node on the other end and using the rel-type (converted to lower-camel-case) as field-name.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a way to generate java classes, but I can think of two approaches you can follow.

- Domain Entities

The principle at use is to wrap the entities around a node (the same approach can be used with relationships as well), see the [Neo4j manual](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorials-java-embedded-entities.html).

- Use Spring Data Neo4j

Only applicable if you want to use the Spring framework. You'll also have to create your own entities, but you'll get ORM-like behavior for free. See the [SDN quick start](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-neo4j/#quick-start).

Comment: I want to avoid writing the Java classes out myself as that information is already encoded in the graph (and the cypher statements) - that's the main aim. I believe both the approaches you listed involve writing out the domain myself.